# I have an Eclipse project which is not using Maven, can I start using Maven in a project?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I installed m2eclipse plugin. I want to create pom.xml in my project which is not using maven.
İn [this site](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363817/Introduction-to-m2eclipse) I found information below about how can I do it but it doesn't work for me.

> Create a Maven POM File
>
> If you already have an Eclipse project which is not using Maven, you
>   can start using Maven in a project by creating a new Maven POM file.
>   m2eclipse provides a wizard to easily create a new POM file inside an
>   existing project. To launch this wizard, select File → New → Other...,
>   type in "maven" in the filter field, and select Maven POM File. This
>   POM creation wizard is shown in Figure 5, “Creating a New POM”:

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use eclipse indigo then simply right-click the project, select Configure > Convert to maven project. If you are not using eclipse indigo you can do something like right-click project > Maven > Enable dependency management (if I remember correctly)